# Making OpenFlow work vertically like a Rolodex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow

I've been looking at integrating the OpenFlow API developed by Alex Fajkowski: http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/ into an app I am working on.

Does anyone know how I can stack the images vertically so that I can scroll the images from top to bottom/bottom to top like a rolodex?

The default behaviour is for OpenFlow to stack the images horizontally and scroll the images from right to left/left to right just like CoverFlow. I've been trying to get my head around how 3D animation is done in Objective-C without much success...

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Hey, Jimbalaya could you pls, share your vertical fix code on OpenFlow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The really easy thing to do is to rotate the whole view with something like this:

```
openFlowView.transform = (CGAffineTransform){0,1,-1,0,0,0};
```

You'll then have to un-rotate all the flowing views (or rotate the images, or whatever).

The better way is to fix OpenFlow, but without looking at its source code, it's not obvious what to change (mostly you should just need to swap "x" and "y").

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It rotated the view just fine. I just now have to manage the images.

As you also mentioned, I'll also continue to see if I can modify the OpenFlow code too.

Comment: All good now. Managed to flip the images around and align the flow. Thank you tc for your suggestion!

Comment: If you're passing views to OpenFlow, you can just set the inverse transformation on subviews (0,-1,1,0,0,0). I'm assuming you're doing that instead of rotating the images themselves!